# Vectorisation and broadcasting

Tags: python, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I need to vectorise the following for loop and I am new to broadcasting and vectorisation (and generally object orientated programming is new to me).

```
width = 1000
height = 400

for v in range(height):
  for u in range(width):
    start[v,u,0] = -0.5 + u / (width-1)
    start[v,u,1] = (-0.5 + v / (height-1)) * height / width
    start[v,u,2] = 0
```

I tried this:

```
start[:,:,0] = [-0.5+u/(width-1) for u  in numpy.arange(width)]
start[:,:,1] = [(-0.5+v/(height-1))*height for v in numpy.arange(height)]
```

But struggling with shapes and find it difficult to understand broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NumPy's [`mgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html#numpy.mgrid) to vectorise your code:

```py
import numpy as np

width = 1000
height = 400
v, u = np.mgrid[0:height, 0:width]

start = np.zeros(shape=(height, width, 3))
start[:, :, 0] = -.5 + u/(width - 1)
start[:, :, 1] = (-.5 + v/(height - 1)) * height / width
```

If you wish to make use of broadcasting simply replace `mgrid`by [`ogrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html#numpy.ogrid).